# How can I have a sliding rectangle overlay between two videos?

Tags: vegas-pro

I have two video tracks which are synced. I now want to have a vertical rectangle having the height of the video, to slide from right to left. Inside this rectangle, track 1 should be seen. Outside of it, track two. Unfortunately I do neither know the name of this technique, nor how to do it in vegas-pro-18.0.